# Collections in #c (ArrayList) in for loop or foreach with index

Tags: c#, arraylist, collections

C# is new to me and I am trying to iterate through a collection, in this case I tried an ArrayList of one of my Classes, which I often used in Java. The goal is to loop and compare the ArrayList and get the index of the current position.

1. Why is it not possibel to initiate an ArrayList with a Type

`ArrayList<MyClass> myAL = new ArrayList<MyClass>();`

2. Why can't I typecast the ArrayList to get access to public methods of MyClass

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
            for (int i=0; i<myAL.Count; i++)
            {
                (MyClass)myAL[i].getSomeValue();
            }
```

3. The only loop that works is the foreach loop, but I don't know how to access the index.

```
foreach (MyClass mc in myAL)
            {
                mc.getSomeValue();
                //index??
            }
```

Comment: Use `List<T>` instead of *obsolete* `ArrayList`

Comment: You should use List<Type> not ArrayList that exists from the beginning of NET history as an untyped collection

Comment: Your second example will work if you write _((MyClass)myAL[i]).getSomeValue();_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unlike Java, `ArrayList` in C# is not generic. If you want a type parameter, you should use `List<T>` from the `System.Collections.Generic` namespace. `List<T>` is actually preferred to `ArrayList` - the latter is still around mostly for backwards compatibility.

```
List<MyClass> myAL = new List<MyClass>();
```

2. You need an additional pair of parentheses for that:

```
ArrayList myAL = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < myAL.Count; i++)
{
    ((MyClass)myAL[i]).getSomeValue();
}
```

But there's no need for casting if you use `List<T>`.

3. You can't access an index directly in the `foreach` loop, but you can define a variable to hold it.

```
int index = 0;
foreach (MyClass mc in myAL)
{
    // do stuff with the list item and an index
    index++;
}
```

But I would recommed using a simple `for`-loop if you need to access an index directly.

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` use Enumerator to loop over collection, index is not part of it, instead it uses `MoveNext`. `MoveNext` forces loop to move to next object

Assume list is like this

```
List<MyClass> list = new List<MyClass>();
```

and then get enumerator in list

```
var listEnumerator  =  list.GetEnumerator();
```

then use `for` loop to iterate over listEnumerator

```
  for(var i = 0; listEnumerator.MoveNext() == true; i++ )
  {
      Console.WriteLine("Index: {0}  and value is: {1}", i, listEnumerator.Current);
  }
```

output

```
Index: 0 and value is: value1 
Index: 1 and value is: value2
```